# Rails 7 importmap jquery error $ undefined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, import-maps

./bin/importmap pin jquery

pinned jquery using this command

In application.js file

```
import jquery from "jquery"
window.jQuery = jquery;
window.$ = jquery;
```

added these lines

but in my view file I am getting $ undefined

```
<script>  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#user_primary_email").focusout(function(){
      $("#user_email").val($(this).val());
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my script tag I added type="module"

```
<script type="module">  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#user_primary_email").focusout(function(){
      $("#user_email").val($(this).val());
    });
  });
</script>
```

And now it is working, I don't know why?

Answer (score 2):

For future visitors...

Here is how you solve this:

1. **Pin jquery**
   `bin/importmap pin jquery`
2. **Use jsdelivr.net or local file in importmap.rb**
   *jspm won't work for some unknown reason*
   **a)** `pin "jquery", to: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.js"`
   **b)** `pin "jquery", to: "jquery.js"`
   *if you use a local file, you need to download jquery.js to app/javascript/jquery.js*
   **You can also pin to a specific version if you want that**
   **c)** `pin "jquery", to: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.0/dist/jquery.js"`
3. **In application.js file you only need to add this**
   `import "jquery"`
4. **When you want to use jquery in a view, you *need use type="module" on the script tag***

```
<script type="module">

 $(document).ready(function(){
   console.log($)
 })
</script>
```

Comment: Why is `type="module"` required?

Comment: The script type="module" attribute is required for using jQuery with importmaps because importmaps are a way to load and manage JavaScript modules.